# LESS css isn't working, what's wrong with this setup

Tags: css, less

I'm new to less css and trying it out. I've done the following

I've added this div

```
<div class="myclass">This is a test of LESS CSS</div>
```

and in the mystyles.less, added this

```
.somepattern(@color: red, @size: 16px) {
    font-size:@size;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:2px solid @color;
}

.myclass {
    .somepattern();
}
```

When I change the syntax to this, it works, which means the problem is in the syntax of caling `.somepattern`. I tried `.somepattern()` and `.somepattern` and `somepattern` but nothing works. The only thing that works is the plain old way of having the code in the class itself

```
.myclass {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: +1 vote because LESS is awesome and anyone trying to get it to work deserves major encouragement :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `.somepattern();` just `somepattern;`

So:

```
.somepattern(@color: red, @size: 16px) {
    font-size:@size;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:2px solid @color;
}

.myclass {
    .somepattern;
}
```

Comment: @zmol - Try removing the () again so it is just `.somepattern;` have you changed the `rel="stylesheet"` to `rel="stylesheet/less"`?

Comment: It eventually worked. I think it might have been a browser cache problem. It eventually worked with `.somepattern;` which I swear I had tried before.

Comment: @zmol There is something with browser cookies... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647779/lesscss-stops-processing-styles

Answer (score 3):

You have to use "stylesheet/less" instead of plain "stylesheet" as the `rel` paramater. It should look like this:

```
<link href="mystyles.less" media="screen" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: +1 I checked code. You have to use `rel="stylesheet/less"` in order for it to work. And the same thing is written on the front page of the LESS project.

Comment: Check the browser's console. A silent error my occur if the address for the `.less` file is wrong. If there is an error inside the Less file itself, a big red error message is shown.