# QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22 in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, wamp, quota

i am using chrome `18.0.1025.162 m` and i have an iframe inside a page.
the iframe uses style.css file.

i am running wamp.
while using it in my localhost i get this error message:

> QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22 in
>   http://127.0.0.1:8009/style.css

i even get this message if the css file is empty.

any idea why i get this message and how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem (I also use less) when I block cookies. I think less needs to use cookies (see 
[LessCSS stops processing styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647779/lesscss-stops-processing-styles))

Answer (score 0):

problem solved (sort of) by removing the [less](http://lesscss.org/) javascript file (less-1.3.0.min.js) from the html.
so i had to use css insted.