# How can I get less.js and bootstrap to work?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to get bootstrap and less.js working but I can't succeed...
I have not worked much with less in the past, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something...
It is runing on a synology server. On runtime it seems to generate the boostrap css as it should "less:sandbox-css-bootstrap" is append to the html but it does'nt get the value from variables.less

Here's my head

```
<meta charset="utf-8">   

<style>
 body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.less">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js"></script>


<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Does it help to close your link tag?

Comment: Nope :/ What I found really strange it's the css is generated but it ignore the values of variables.less

Comment: add `type="text/javascript"` to the bootstrap script tag.

Comment: Have you tried loading your Less ``js`` before your ``.less`` ``<link>``?

Comment: @Mark I allready tried...

Comment: @Nick I tried too, css isnt generated then...

Comment: What does your browser's console say? Are you getting any warning/404 messages for resources?

Comment: Nope it says nothing... It's just driving me crazy ;)

Comment: The answer to this question may be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647779/lesscss-stops-processing-styles

Answer (score 4):

Change the order of your initialization. Place dependencies above the others. like place bootstrap.less above all other CSS's